# Shoulda indication for pending tests

Tags: ruby, shoulda

Using RSpec you have:

spec.rb

```
describe Magic, "stuff of magic" do
   it "should do some crazy magic" do
      # crazy magic
   end

   it "should do some advanced magic"
end
```

Running it as

```
rspec spec.rb
```

The output would look like this

```
.*
Pending:
   Magic stuff of magic should do some advanced magic
       # Not yet implemented

2 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

Now, can you get some sort of indication of pending tests then using Shoulda? Can you even have pending (not yet implemented) tests with Shoulda?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I use this gem as `rspec` is fine by me and [thoughtbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/shoulda-rails3-and-beyond) whom created `shoulda` but...

You can probably still use the `pending` method e.g.

```
describe Magic, "stuff of magic" do
  it { should "do some crazy magic" do
         # crazy magic
       end
     }

  it { 
       should "do some advanced magic" do 
         pending "someday"
       end
     }
end
```

but there is also a matcher called `should_eventually` that seems like it might provide this functionality

```
describe Magic, "stuff of magic" do
  it "should do some crazy magic" do
     # crazy magic
  end

  it {should_eventually "do some advanced magic"}
end
```

Although `shoulda` seems better suited for single line tests like

```
it{ should respond_to?(:crazy_magic)}
it{ should allow_value("crazy").for(:type_of_magic)}
it{ should_not allow_value("boring").for(:type_of_magic)}
```